# Computing expectation using Binomial Expansion

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, binomial-theorem

I'm solving for a problem. I got this probability mass function
$$
P(X=x) = \begin{pmatrix} x-1 \\ n-1 \end{pmatrix} p^n(1-p)^{x-n} \hspace{1cm}; x=n,n+1,...
$$

I should find the expectation

$$
E(\frac{n-1}{x-1})
$$

I started solving it

$
E(\frac{n-1}{x-1}) = \sum_{x=n}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{x-1} \begin{pmatrix} x-1 \\ n-1 \end{pmatrix} p^n(1-p)^{x-n}
$

$
\hspace{1.6cm} = \sum_{x=n}^{\infty} \begin{pmatrix} x-2 \\ n-2 \end{pmatrix} p^n(1-p)^{x-n}
$

$
\hspace{1.6cm} = p^n\sum_{x=n}^{\infty} \begin{pmatrix} x-2 \\ n-2 \end{pmatrix}(1-p)^{x-n}
$

$
\hspace{1.6cm} = p^n\sum_{x=n}^{\infty} \frac{(x-2)!}{[(x-2)-(n-2)]!(n-2)!}(1-p)^{x-n}
$

$
\hspace{1.6cm} = p^n\sum_{x=n}^{\infty} \frac{(x-2)!}{(x-n)!(n-2)!}(1-p)^{x-n}
$

I'm stuck at this point. I don't know how to proceed. Can someone help me on how to solve or proceed further. I think Binomial Expansion might be useful but I don't know how to apply it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking from your las step which can be re-written as
$$E=p^n\sum_{x=n}^{\infty} {x-2 \choose n-2} (1-p)^{x-n}=p^n\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {j+n-2 \choose j} (1-p)^j=p^n[1-(1-p)]^{-(n-2)-1}=p.$$
$j=x-n$ used in above.
Here we have also used the binomial series for negative integer index as:
$$\sum_{J=0}^{\infty} {J+N \choose J} Z^{J}=(1-Z)^{-N-1}$$

Comment: How did $(1-p)^{x-n}$ become $x^j$. I'm not getting this part

Comment: Oh! sorry it was a typo.

Comment: One more doubt. How did $n-2$ become $j$ in the combinations after writing $j = x-n$

Comment: Because ${j+n-2\choose n-2}={j+n-2 \choose j}$ just like ${n \choose k}={n \choose n-k}$